# is there a way to understand if a particular AD group is synchronized or not?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, active-directory, sync, synchronization

in SharePoint 2013, is there a way to troubleshoot and confirm if a particular AD group is synchronized or not?

Comment: You can check by going any site setting of any site -> users permission -> and check permission from the ribbon and enter the AD group in that and wait to populate the group name, if it's populate the AD group name then you can confirm its syncronized

Comment: No, that's not synchronization, that's simply checking permissions. Synchronization has a specific meaning and that is synchronization into the UPSA. People Picker has nothing to do with sync.